# Need help on Hibernate and JPQL syntax

Tags: hibernate, jpql

I am new to play framework and hibernate , I have a simple problem that I am unable to solve

```
public static void listMembers(int page,int pageSize,String[] fields,String[] values) { 
    List<Member> members = Member.find(query,params).fetch();
    render(members);
}
```

I am unsure how to write the query and the params
as I want each field to be checked against corresponding value

something like this ( which generates errors) :

```
public static void listMembers(int page,int pageSize,String[] fields,String[] values) { 
    String query = "" ;
    String[] params = new String[values.length*2] ;
    int i = 0 ;
    for(i = 0 ; i < fields.length-1 ; i+=2 ) {
        query += "?"+(i+1)+" like ?"+(i+2)+" AND" ;
        params[i]   = fields[i] ;
        params[i+1] = "%"+values[i]+"%" ;
    }
    query += "?"+(i+1)+" like ?"+(i+2) ;
    params[i]   = fields[i] ;
    params[i+1] = values[i] ;


    List<Member> members = Member.find(query,params).fetch();
    render(members);
}
```

Edit:
Such that the query will be :

```
?1 like ?2 AND ?3 like ?4 AND .....
```

and params will be:

```
field1,%value1%,field2,%value2%,...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to use setParameter() and EntityManager:

```
String jpql = "select m from Member m where ";
for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
 jpql += (i > 0 ? " AND " : "") + fields[i] + " like '%?%' ";
}
Query q = entityManager.createQuery(jpql);
for (int i = 1; i <= values; i++) {
 q.setParameter(i, values[i]);
}
List<Members> members = q.getResultList();
```